# How to get object from dropdown menu?

Tags: python, django

In my Django application I have these models:

```
class BaseModel(ModelWithStamps):
    identifier = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class Model(BaseModel):
    def __str__(self):
        name = self.name_type()
        return f'{name}: {self.identifier}'

class Merch(Name):
    merch_id = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=255, verbose_name="Merchant ID")

class Term(Name):
    merch_fk = models.ForeignKey(Merc, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
```

And in the forms I have a Term dropdown. In the serializer in this part it giving me this error:

Error:     raise ValueError(
ValueError: Cannot assign "'4545646'": "Term.merch_fk" must be a "Merch" instance.

```
serializer.py
   # Update the model
            for (key, value) in field_value.items():

                setattr(related, key, value)
            related.save()
```

NOTE:

```
if key == "merch_fk":
    split_line = value.split(':')
    value = Merch.objects.get(merch_id=split_line[1].strip())
```

It doesn't work because there can be multiple objects with the same merch_id

How can I fix it?